# Opera doesn't let me change default browser for html pages

Tags: firefox, browser, opera, file-extension

Basically, title says it all. I have to move from Opera browser to Mozilla Firefox, but I'm unable to switch default application for html and htm pages. When I do this from standard file dialog, the icon of the file still doesn't change. If I remove Opera, I'm still unable to select the default browser. But when I install Opera back again, the files are automatically setting to Opera as default viewer.

My system is Windows 7 Home Basic.

Comment: "When I do *this* from standard file dialog" is unclear. You need to say exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Default Programs to restore IE as default browser, reboot when done to be safe, launch Firefox and set it as the default browser when asked.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to change the icon of the file would be to go into your Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs.

There will be an option in there for "Associate a file type or protocol with a program" - click this option which will move you to another screen.

When the new screen opens, scroll down the list until you find the .htm and .html file extensions.
[image: Change File Association]

Double-click both of them and change the associated application in the window that appears.

This will change the icon of the file to the Firefox icon.

To change the actual default Internet Browser application, again, in the same Control Panel location above, chose the "Set your default programs" option & then select Firefox & click "Set this program as default"
[image: Set Firefox as Default]

The final solution is to open Firefox & then go to the options menu & click the "Make Default" button in the General settings to ensure Firefox is the default web browser.

HTH